# Office.js has not been fully loaded yet :Outlook Angular add-in

Tags: angular, office-js

I have working on Outlook Add-in using Angular. I am getting an error in Outlook for Windows that a component is not loading after loading index page. This is not happening with Outlook Web App using Chrome and Firefox.

Error message is :

```js
SCRIPT5022: Office.js has not been fully loaded yet. Please try again 
later or make sure to add your initialization code on the Office.initialize function.
polyfills.bundle.js (2741,25)
```

this is my index.ts

```ts
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

declare let Office:any;

function launch() {
  const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
  platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then((success: any) => {
      console.log('SampleAddin: bootstrap success', success);
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('SampleAddin: bootstrap error', error);
    });
}

Office.initialize = reason => {
   console.log('Office intialize.....');

  $(document).ready(function () {   

    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }

    launch();

   });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer for my own question : I couldn't loading component in outlook mac and windows. But after adding this to polyfills.ts:

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
```

it's working in IE 11 also and it seems that this didn't break other browsers.

Comment: One note, with Outlook for Mac it isn't using IE11 but rather a custom WebKit implementation. That said, this is interesting. I'm not sure I understand why you needed a shim to get Office.initialize() to fire off. I'm super curious what component was breaking things that this shim fixed.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned IE 11 working that because it was previously not worked and also outlook on windows.Office.initialize() fire happen in polyfills.bundle.js. I think shims is used to makes browser competability. ( https://angular.io/guide/browser-support )

Comment: That is correct, shims and polyfills are used for cross-browser compatibility. What is odd here however is that you're not getting any other errors. Normally I would expect to see additional errors that point to the root cause of initialize not getting called. It is also odd that this failed for both Mac and Windows considering the browser engines are quite different.

Comment: @SandunTharaka I had the original issue of my Angular Add-In not working in desktop versions of Outlook, as well. The added polyfill did help IE support, but I have yet to find a solution that adds support for desktop versions. Have you had any luck since you posted this?

Comment: @cbrawl after importing shim, Get its working on Outlook Desktop versions ( Windows and Mac)

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs,

you have to initialize a add-in using Office.onReady().

Please refer the docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/initialize-add-in

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31391841)